# Protected in Ruby

Tags: ruby, protected

I have this question:

> Class members in Ruby marked as protected
>
> a. Can only be accessed by the exact instance that owns those members
>    b. (a), and also any other instances of that class
>    c. (a), (b), and also any subclasses of that class
>    d. (a), and any module code imported into that class

The answer I'm told is b. But I think it should be c, as a subclass is also an instance of the super class (according to our notes) I was hoping someone with some more Ruby knowledge could help me out.

Comment: Interesting sidenote, the creator of Ruby seems to regret ever introducing the protected method...
http://junichiito.blogspot.com/2012/03/matz-answers-why-ruby-lets-sub-classes.html

Comment: B & C are equivalent, C is just more explicit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"A protected method is like a private method in that it can only be invoked from within the implementation of a class or its subclasses. (...)" (The Ruby Programming Language, Flanagan & Matsumoto, page 232)

So yes, answer c seems correct.

Comment: The Ruby Programming Language is by Flanagan and Matsumoto.